# C++ remove std::list element in loop issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, iterator, erase

Good day. I want to understand, why this works good:

```
    std::list<Contact>::iterator it = contacts.begin();

    while (it != contacts.end()) {
        if ((*it).status == Contact::Status::disconnected) {
            (*it).handler.detach();
            it = contacts.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            it++;
        }   
    }
```

but this causes crash with message "abort() has been called":

```
    contacts.remove_if([](Contact c) {
        if (c.status != Contact::Status::disconnected)
            return false;

        c.handler.detach();

        return true;
    });
```

All this executes in separated thread inside critical section. List and critical section declared globally as:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;
std::list<Contact> contacts;
```

Comment: Probably your `Contact` is not copy-safe. Where is your [MCVE]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your lambda for `remove_if`, you're passing in a **copy** of the Contact, and detaching from that one.  The original in the list does not get detached.  Pass in a reference instead:  `remove_if([](Contact &c)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively `detach`ing a brand new `Contact` object due to your `remove_if` defintion taking by Value.

This is in contrast to the iterator version where you are `detach`ing the actual Contact object inside of your `contacts` vector